# Can I write a Parquet file to the local file system?

Tags: python, parquet

New to Parquet. I have a Parquet file - we'll call it `momma.parquet` - that was produced by reading several "baby" Parquet files on the local file system. The "baby" Parquet files were created by `pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet()`.

What I need to do is write `momma.parquet` to the file system. I've read tons of posts and the Parquet documentation, and haven't come up with a solution to what I assumed would be a pretty simple process. The fastparquet documentation calls for `write('outfile.parq', df)` which takes a dataframe as an argument which I shouldn't need to do.

Here's my code that I hoped would accomplish that:

```
def make_momma_parquet(csv_filepath, parquet_filepath, numeric_cols, datetime_cols):
       """Create a parquet from a list of other parquet files and
       write it to the local filesystem
       :param csv_filepath: string
       :param parquet_filepath:
       :param numeric_cols: list of strings
       :param datetime_cols:  list of strings
       """

       # list of parquet files
       parquet_files = []

       # source Dask df:
       ddf = dd.read_csv(csv_filepath, blocksize='600MB', dtype='object')

       # Baby One:
       # create a Pandas dataframe
       numeric_df = ddf[numeric_cols].compute()
       # do some stuff with the Pandas dataframe then
       # write the parquet file
       numeric_df.to_parquet(parquet_filepath)
       parquet_files.append(parquet_filepath)

       # Baby two:
       # create a Pandas dataframe
       datetime_df = ddf[datetime_cols].compute()
       # do some stuff with the Pandas dataframe then
       # write the parquet file
       datetime_df.to_parquet(parquet_filepath)
       parquet_files.append(parquet_filepath)

       # Momma
       hist_parquet = fastparquet.ParquetFile(parquet_files)
       # write the parquet file to the filesystem
```

Comment: Can you show the code used to create `momma.parquet`?  I agree that it does seem like [`fastparquet`](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) lacks an API to write a file directly.  Maybe `parquet_file.to_pandas().to_parquet()`?

Comment: Added the code to the question as you suggested

Comment: I don't understand your approach. Why not just write everything (datetime cols / numeric cols) at once? `ddf[datetime_cols + numeric_cols].compute().to_parquet("moma.parquet")`

Comment: Dirty data. Dealing with it in Pandas is easier. As I become more familiar with Dask/Parquet maybe I won't ask dumb questions.